# Filter for a single file in JSF application

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

I have one file (FileUpload.xhtml) which needs to protected from unauthorized access. So whenever someone tries to access FileUpload.xhtml, he has to go through the filter. This file is located as /web/sign/FileUpload.xhtml. There are some other files also that are present in the same directory as FileUpload.xhtml which should not go though this filter. I tries url patterns like

```
/web/sign/FileUpload.xhtml
/web/sign/FileUpload.xhtml*
/web/sign/FileUpload*
```

But none on them seems to work. But the url pattern :

```
/web/sign/*
```

works. But it also includes other files that are present with FileUpload.xhtml that I do not want to go through this filter. How to go about this problem?

Just to be more clear. I will be checking the request parameter to authorize the page. If someone accessing the page like

```
http://localhost:8888/CodesignWebApp/web/sign/FileUpload.xhtml?sign=Driver
```

I will check value of 'sign' parameter against the user, to see if he has the privilege to use Driver as sign value. Is this the right way to go about it?

Filter entries from web.xml :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Are there other filter patterns specified in your web.xml? Post it here

Comment: @kolossus Filter entries from web.xml added.

Comment: Shouldn't you think of other ways to protect server resources like JAAS instead?